# Merge Rows of table

Tags: sql-server

Want to merge rows into 2 by `ID`  need to merge columns `DocStatus` and `Release Date` by skipping empty values.

[image]

Comment: Refer image for output reference.

Answer (score 1):

basically you can use GROUP BY with aggregate function. something like below

```
SELECT   ID, somecol, max(another_column), min(yet_another_column)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY ID, somecol
```